# How to migrate ASP.net 4 IdentityConfig to ASP.net 5

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I want to migrate my web application using  ASP.net 4 Identity 2 to the new ASP.net Identity in ASP.net 5 (Beta 7).

However in ASP.net 5 the IdentityConfig.cs and the App_Start folder no longer exist.

In ASP.net 4 I made use of the ApplicationUserManager helper class  in the IdentityConfig.cs  as described in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762428/ASP-NET-MVC-and-Identity-Understanding-the-Basics) that derives from the UserManager class.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
```

The current [migration page](http://mvc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migration/migratingauthmembership.html) in the ASP.net docs also doesn't give an indication how to migrate this code to ASP.net 5.

Comment: I recommend create a new asp.net 5 app using vs2015 with the beta7 tooling installed. The app will use identity and you can study the app to learn about all the changes. There are lots and lots of changes.